# How to rename target folder of PHP extractTo prior to extraction

Tags: php, zip

I am attempting to update the contents of a folder on server with contents received from a ZIP.
However, if the target folder is not named the same as my ZIP, it creates a new folder, instead of overwriting the existing one.

This few lines of PHP should explain what I try to achieve:

```
$zip = new ZipArchive;
$res = $zip->open($new_version_zip);
if ($res===TRUE) {
  $zip->extractTo( '/path/to/install/install_folder_name' );
  $zip->close();
}
```

If my zip was named `install_folder_name`, this code will overwrite current contents of `/path/to/install/install_folder_name` just fine. **Good.**

If my zip was named `anything`, it will create a new folder named `anything` in `/path/to/install/`. **Bad.**

I thus want to *rename the ZIP before extracting it* so the extracted product has the exact name of `install_folder_name`.
It seems not possible, and the only I could think of would be a (rather weird) process of:

- unzip ZIP that might be named `anything`
- rename to `install_folder_name`
- re-zip
- unzip again

Is there a better solution?

**UPDATE as per answers requests**
The ZIP, as well the target, is not just a single file.
It is a folder, with many folders inside, and many files. An *app*, not a single file.

Comment: You should refine your question, because it does *not* describe your problem correctly.

Comment: I have added a note to the bottom of the question attesting that it is a zip with folders and files. Also to denote how the initial question mentions _contents_, not _content_. We are speaking of many items inside the main folder :)

So, I guess, short answer: <strong>not possible</strong>. Unzip, rename, rezip, unzip is the solution.